# C++ multi level inheritance with virtual functions

Tags: c++, c++17

I am a bit confused about multi-level inheritance and virtual functions in C++. In the example below, I have 3 levels with `Bottom` inheriting from `Middle` inheriting from `Top`.

If I declare the function in `Top` as `virtual` and use a pointer of type `Middle`, it still overrides the function declared in `Middle` even though it's not declared `virtual`.

I was expecting:

```
Middle* ptr = new Bottom();
ptr->hello(); // Expectation: "Hello Middle"  (Actual: "Hello Bottom")
```

and

```
Top* ptr = new Bottom();
ptr->hello(); // "Hello Bottom"
```

But that doesn't seem to be the case. Why is this?

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>

//  Top
//   ^
// Middle
//   ^
// Bottom

struct Top {
  // This is set to virtual.
  virtual void hello() { std::cout << "Hello Top\n"; }
};

struct Middle : public Top {
  // But not this.
  void hello() { std::cout << "Hello Middle\n"; }
};

struct Bottom : public Middle {
  // So why is this called if the type is Middle?
  void hello() { std::cout << "Hello Bottom\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Middle *ptr = new Bottom(); // Will use hello() in Bottom.
  // Top *ptr = new Bottom(); // Same result as the above.
  ptr->hello();
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use of the keyword `virtual` in derived classes is not mandatory, what matters is it’s presence in the base class.

Comment: @hyde - So there is no way to have virtual work only on `Top` and not on `Middle`? The way I'm expecting it?

Comment: There is no way to have mixed virtual/non-virtual behavior for a specific function in an inheritance chain. The specification with `virtual` of the first declaration in the direction Base → Derived influences the whole chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Derived functions are [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) no matter you specify them virtual or not if the base function was virtual:

> If some member function vf is declared as virtual in a class Base, and
>   some class Derived, which is derived, directly or indirectly, from
>   Base, has a declaration for member function with the same
>
> name parameter type list (but not the return type) cv-qualifiers
>   ref-qualifiers Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual
>   **(whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration)** and
>   overrides Base::vf (**whether or not the word override is used in its
>   declaration**).

---

If you wanted to access the base functions you can use:

```
ptr->Top::hello();

Middle* ptr2 = new Bottom();
ptr2->Middle::hello();

delete ptr;
delete ptr2;
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Tm7oYb)

Answer (score 1):

Because that base class function declared virtual it is no matter the function in derived class declared virtual or not virtual.